# Incrementing through subroutines in C for loop

Tags: c++, c, for-loop, arduino

I have five identical DS2401 unique ID chips attached to an Arduino, and I wish to read the serial number from each consecutively into RAM so that I can send the data over serial.

I have each one initialised separately, so that I can call the code to retrieve the serial number with ds24_0.getSerialNumber(), ds24_1.getSerialNumber() etc.

If I were to build these into a for loop, how do I get the code to call ds24_i, where i is the loop iteration number? Am I going about this the wrong way?

```
OneWire oneWire_0(10);
DS2401 ds24_0(&oneWire_0);
OneWire oneWire_1(A0);
DS2401 ds24_1(&oneWire_1);
OneWire oneWire_2(A1);
DS2401 ds24_2(&oneWire_2);
OneWire oneWire_3(A2);
DS2401 ds24_3(&oneWire_3);
OneWire oneWire_4(A3);
DS2401 ds24_4(&oneWire_4);

//snip

void idRequest()
{
  uint8_t serialNumber[5][6];
  uint8_t result[5];

  result[0] = ds24_0.init();  //how do I loop this
  result[1] = ds24_1.init();
  result[2] = ds24_2.init();
  result[3] = ds24_3.init();
  result[4] = ds24_4.init();

  if(result[0] == DS2401_SUCCESS) 
  {
    ds24_0.getSerialNumber(serialNumber[0]);  //how do I loop this also?
  }

  else if(result[0] == DS2401_CRC_FAIL || DS2401_NOT_DS2401 || DS2401_NO_WIRE) 
    {
      for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
      {
        serialNumber[0][i] = 0;
      }
    }
//assemble packet here
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are `ds24_0` and so on? Where are they defined?

Comment: @PaulHankin I have added the definitions to the code

Comment: You define them yourself? Why not use an array rather than 5 variables?

Comment: @PaulHankin because I don't know how to do that, that's why I wrote this post.

Comment: @JoeofLoath what is A1, A2, A3 ... ?

Comment: @Landstalker pin assignments. Pin 10, pin A0, pin A1 etc.

Comment: @JoeofLoath What is the type of A1, A2, ...  (your Pin 10, Pin A0) it an object of some class ?

Comment: @Landstalker they are uint8_t as provided by arduino.h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In define:

```
 #define NB_PIN 5
```

In code:

```
 uint8_t tabUnit[NB_PIN]={10, 0xA0, 0xA1, 0xA2, 0xA3};
 OneWire *tabOneWire[NB_PIN];
 DS2401  *tabDS2401[NB_PIN];
 uint8_t  result[NB_PIN];

 for ( int i=0; i<NB_PIN; i++)
 {
   tabOneWire[i] = new OneWire (tabUnit[i]);
   tabDS2401 [i] = new DS2401 (tabOneWire[i]);
   result [i]    = tabDS2401[i]->init();
 }

 // .........

 for ( int i=0; i<NB_PIN; i++)
 {
    delete tabDS2401 [i];
    delete tabOneWire[i];
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! If I'm following this correctly we create instances of onewire and ds2401 locally, use them iteratively, then delete them again?

Comment: @JoeofLoath with operator `new` your objects can be used from any scope and not just locally (as I didn't know your constraints in terms of scope visibility). At the end of their use, you must destroy them to free resources as well as not to have memory leaks.

Comment: Thank you, this is working now! I had one issue - tabDS2401 [i] = new DS2401 (*tabOneWire[i]); fails to compile as tabOneWire[i] is already a pointer - remove the asterisk and it compiles and runs properly.

Comment: @JoeofLoath Ok, Thanks for the remark. I update the post code.

Answer (score 0):

Put the ds24's in an array.

```
auto ds24s = {ds24_0, ds24_1, ds24_2, ds24_3, ds24_4};
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    result[i] = ds24s[i].init();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm unfamiliar with the auto keyword. However, this fails - looks like an Arduino bug: https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/6609

Comment: Are you sure that copying DS2401 objects is sensible?